# The screen doesn't show anything: passing values to a list

Tags: c, list

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "trips.h"


void load_fromfiles(char* argv[], tripnode* _triplist, stationnode* _stationlist)
{
    FILE* tripsfptr=NULL;
    tripsfptr=fopen(argv[3], "r");
    if(tripsfptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: File could not be opened\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    load_tripfile(&_triplist, tripsfptr);

    fclose(tripsfptr);
}



void load_tripfile(tripnode** _triplist, FILE* _fp)
{
    trip_data triptoread;
    char separator[]=",/:";
    char buffer[BUFSIZE]={'\0'};
    char string1[BUFSIZE]={'\0'};
    char string2[BUFSIZE]={'\0'};
    char string3[BUFSIZE]={'\0'};
    char* token=NULL;
    char* help=NULL;

    while(fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, _fp)!=NULL)
    {
        sscanf(buffer, "%s %s %s", string1, string2, string3);
        token=strtok(string1, separator);
        triptoread.tripID= strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        triptoread.timespan= strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        triptoread.datebegin.month=strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        triptoread.datebegin.day=strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        triptoread.datebegin.year=strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(string2, separator);
        triptoread.timebegin.hour=strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        triptoread.timebegin.minute=strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        triptoread.stationstartID=strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        triptoread.dateend.month=strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        triptoread.dateend.day=strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        triptoread.dateend.year=strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(string3, separator);
        triptoread.timeend.hour=strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        triptoread.timeend.minute=strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        triptoread.stationstopID=strtol(token,&help,10);
        token=strtok(NULL, separator);
        if(strcmp(token,"Casual")!=0 && strcmp(token,"Registered")!=0)
        {
            strcpy(triptoread.bikeID, token);
            token=strtok(NULL, separator);

        }

        if(strcmp(token, "Casual")==0)
        {
            triptoread.user.type=0;
            triptoread.user.birthyear=-1;
            triptoread.user.gender=-1;
        }

        else
        {
            triptoread.user.type=1;
            token=strtok(NULL, separator);
            triptoread.user.birthyear=strtol(token,&help,10);
            token=strtok(NULL, separator);
            if(strcmp(token, "Male")==0)
                triptoread.user.gender=1;
            else
                triptoread.user.gender=0;
        }

        *_triplist=InsertTripList(*_triplist, triptoread);

    }
}

tripnode* NewTripNode(trip_data _trip)
{
    tripnode* newnode=NULL;
    newnode=(tripnode*)malloc(sizeof(tripnode));
    if(newnode==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Memory not correctly allocated\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    newnode->trip_file=_trip;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    newnode->prev=NULL;

    return newnode;
}

tripnode* InsertTripList(tripnode* _headtrip, trip_data _trip)
{
    tripnode* newtailtrip=NULL;
    newtailtrip=NewTripNode(_trip);
    tripnode* aux=NULL;

    if(_headtrip==NULL)
    {
        return newtailtrip;
    }

    aux=_headtrip;

    while (aux->next!=NULL)
    {
        aux=aux->next;
    }

    aux->next=newtailtrip;
    newtailtrip->prev=aux;

    return _headtrip;

}
```

The problem is: I have the line

*_triplist=InsertTripList(*_triplist, triptoread);

uncommented and

```
    while (aux->next!=NULL)
    {
        aux=aux->next;
    }
```

The program simply shows a black screen and a cursor. 
I tried to print a word and it just printed it infinitely.
What's going on?

Here I have the structures I don't know if it helps.
Also I want to note that I don't have any of that problems

```
typedef struct
{
    int hour;
    int minute;
} ttime;


typedef struct
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} ddate;


typedef struct
{
    int type;
    int birthyear;
    int gender;
} person;


typedef struct
{
    int tripID;
    int timespan;
    ttime timebegin;
    ttime timeend;
    ddate datebegin;
    ddate dateend;
    char bikeID[7];
    person user;
    int stationstartID;
    int stationstopID;

} trip_data;

typedef struct trip
{
    trip_data trip_file;
    struct trip *prev;
    struct trip *next;
} tripnode;
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the problem code with your debugger?

Comment: We are not a debugging service. Where is the [mcve]?